# Anyone hesitant to work extra for User******s?

Tags: discussion

Just curious is anyone else hesitant to work extra to answer questions for users who haven't even picked a user name other then the User***** one? I will admit I try not to go past my personal knowledge or a basic google. Yet if they have a user name I am much more apt to try to get to the meat of the answer.

I guess in my userism(sp?) I tend to think if they did not fill that out at least, they probably won't upvote or accept an answer. And we all know that is the point right? :)

Comment: What if it was chosen as such? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14048/user0x36e0

Comment: I'm sure we discussed possible policies on openid usernames just last week, but as usual the search is failing me. :(

Answer (score 17):

A large percentage of my interest is to answer the question, not for the original author, but **for the other people reading**. In reality, you are *really* talking over their shoulder to a much larger audience.

So, no, I can't say I take the original author's name much into account. The only time the original author influences the effort I put into an answer is when I feel like they are not putting much effort into the question... then I feel like I am just being taken advantage of.

Answer (score 9):

For *me*, The fact that they don't really care doesn't really affect my reaction to their question.

> A rose by any other name would <s>smell just as sweet</s> still get me some rep ;)

Comment: mmmMMMMM, fresh rep!

Comment: Roses are red, violets are blue, and all this rep is for you.

Answer (score 8):

Not if the question is any good.

And if the question sucks I don't care if the users has a proper name.

Oh, I notice and avoid certain users---ones who have annoyed me in the past---but I don't judge people for being new.

Comment: Wouldn't say I judge for them being new just not caring enough about the site/community to reflect themselves to us.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say that I even notice who posted the question.  I know that if I don't answer it as swiftly as possible, someone will beat me to the punch, and I will lose the first mover advantage.

So I put the same effort into them as any other question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't necessarily feel hesitance, but...if we test by the opposite case (a known user with an accept rate of 100% and maybe a decent rep), I'm  more likely to *want* to give these other kind of user's question *more* of my time.

So, being unnamed isn't so much the issue, except by association--abandoned questions, low chance of even knowing to upvote or accept an answer, perceived lower chance of them interacting in an intelligent manner (part and parcel with being here-and-gone, I think, more than a "smart people are registered and dumb people aren't" bias), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I gotta say: Anyone who's username starts with "User" and ends with a number is just asking for it. I mean, how dare they not intuitively know how to update their profile and choose a more suitable username, such as "Urdnot the Kronan Has a Posse" or "I Am Your King" or "Changing My Meta Name is Cool" or even (how boring) their own names?

Not only do I not answer their questions, I downvote their posts. All of them. In fact, I super *mega* downvote all their posts. Then I crush their heads! Crush! Crush!

That rule applies to anyone, I think, whose username starts with "User."

Oh, wait. Oops ... :)

Comment: +1 for the larfs and as a reconciliatory gesture to userXXXXers.